# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: development, web-part, visual-studio, excel, office

I am getting the following error: `The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.` while I am trying to read an excel file and than to populate it in `GridView`, within a `VisualWebPart`

I have found some solutions while googling my error, one of these was to install `2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components.` I installed this but still not working also I installed this one: `Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable` but again it is not working.

I saw some posts on some forums that I have to change the application platform from `x64` to `x86` but I cannot do this because sharepoint runs only `x64` apps.

I'm using `32bit Office Professional Plus` installed on my `E drive` while system is in `C drive` because of space.

I have the following code:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "";
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string fileLocation = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_GlobalResources/" + fileName);

            FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileLocation);

            //Check whether file extension is xls or xslx

            if (fileExtension == ".xls")
            {
                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            }
            else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
            {
                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            }

            //Create OleDB Connection and OleDb Command

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();
            con.Open();
            DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";
            dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
            con.Close();
            GridView1.DataSource = dtExcelRecords;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Please someone help me.

Comment: where's this excel file located ? is it uploaded to document library in SharePoint?

Comment: @M.Qassas Yes i would like to read data from excel which is located in document library.

Comment: you can try to use REST as mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496608/read-excel-file-stored-in-sharepoint-document-library

Comment: I want to read the file before upload it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider` depends on the current office installation is it 32 bit or 64 bit.

**In your case,** you already installed `32bit Office Professional Plus` so you should target the `Solution Platform` from `"Any CPU"` to `"x86"` based on office installation.

**But** Setting `Platform target` to `"x86"` will not be working with SharePoint, so try to uninstall `32bit Office Professional Plus` then install `Office 64 bit`that should solve your issue.

Check also other suggestions at ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Comment: Thank you so much, after I've uninstalled all products related to office 32bit I finally make it to work. Thanks.